# Node JS + ExpressJS - net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app built on ExpressJS and NodeJS. We hosted it at Linode server. The app is served at port 3000.

The app has been working for a year but recently we keep getting the connection errors. Sometimes it is ok. But most of time not.

The errors we get usually are:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/stylesheets/bootstrap-tagsinput.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 0.0.0.0/:7

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/stylesheets/jasny-bootstrap/jasny-bootstrap.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 0.0.0.0/:7

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/javascripts/jquery.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 0.0.0.0/:63 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/stylesheets/fonts.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:63

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:64 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/javascripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:65 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/javascripts/jasny-bootstrap/jasny-bootstrap.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:65

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/vendors/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:66 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/javascripts/common.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:67 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:64 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/pollen-dustbox-transparent.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:52 

GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/carbon-transparent.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0.0.0.0/:64
```

Sometimes the browser will just say:

```
This site can't be reached.
```

Any ideas what is causing this? How can I fix this?

**Note** that I use **0.0.0.0** as an example. not sure if I should share our app ip address. don't want to get hacked!

**EDIT:**

I don't see the port 3000 is in the list when I run `netstat`:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15065/mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3262/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3265/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3838            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3267/shiny-server
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      3262/systemd-resolv
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1514/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3265/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           3262/systemd-resolv
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           3260/dhcpcd
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                3262/systemd-resolv
```

Is it a problem from Linode server or the application level error? Any thoughts?

Comment: A HTTP request going to 0.0.0.0 is unusual. Where does that IP come from?

Comment: that is my localhost. do you need my app address at Linode server?

Comment: No, it's just that "localhost" is 127.0.0.1. I would not expect a GET request to 0.0.0.0 to work.

Comment: I use 0.0.0.0  as an example. not sure if I should share our app ip address. don't want to get hacked!

Comment: Ah, that's a different matter. You should use 127.0.0.1 then for the sake of the example. In fact, if your server runs on 0.0.0.0 then you should actually be able to reach the site at 127.0.0.1, so that you wouldn't have to do any IP replacements in the logs at all. `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` does not leave much room for interpretation, though.

Comment: @Tomalak I have updated my question with the output of `netstat`. Have a look. Is it a problem from Linode server or the application level error? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when in my "security" (brandmauer or how it's called) on my windows machine the 80 port was disabled.
After enabling it - everything worked fine.

As you are using 3000 port - check if it's enabled.

One more issue i had was the same on the router (on my wify router i had to set that i want 80 port to forward requests to my pc 80 port ). If you are using router chack that configurations too.

Also it is better to make nginx server and do the reverse proxy to the 3000 port, you can chack the manuals available online.

Comment: thanks. how can I check if 3000 port is disabled or not?

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall/

Comment: i dont use windows. i am on linux.

Comment: sry, but i think you'v got the idea.. Im not using linux, so cant tell where to look it there, but you need broundmire settings.. something like that..